# What's a good free tool for investigating unintentional object retention in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

My multithreaded Java program crashes because it runs out of heap space and I don't think it should.  Assuming the culprit is unintentional object retention, what's a good free tool to investigate what objects are being unintentionally retained?

My IDE is Eclipse.

Comment: I think Java is quite good at garbage collection. So, if nobody touch it or run it anymore, it would be auto garbage collected, right? So, how can your case happen?

Comment: vodkhang: If nobody _references_ it, it is eligible for garbage collection. If it quite possible to accidentally keep a reference without needing it anymore.

Comment: @vodkhang: there are a *lot* of cases where there are memory leaks in Java.  The GC gives the **totally false** impression that there aren't memory leak but anyone who's been working with Java for some time does know that there are indeed a lot of sources of memory leaks.  Here's an article explaining how to hunt and deals with these memory leaks, but which fist starts with an explanation clearing up your misconception on the subject:   http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/05/0816_GuptaPalanki/

Comment: *"objects being unintentionally retained"* means *"memory leak"* (see IBM article linked above).  A typical way to track these is to run a profiler, take an object dump of your app after, say, 5 minutes, then take a dump once leaks starts to happen and compare with the first dump.  I've used HPJMeter many years ago (when it wasn't HP-specific), then now typically VisualVM to analyze such issues.

Comment: @WizardOfOdds I started on C around 1980 and Java around 199(6?).  I distinguish between Java's unintentional object retention and C's memory leaking.

Comment: No "unintentional object retention" does not mean "memory leak".  Memory is leaked when the program has no reference to said memory and hence cannot access it.  An exact garbage collector will always return unreferenced memory to the free list.  When an object is unintentionally retained, there is still some global reference to it.  Heap tracing tools can be used to find such a reference.  Leaked memory cannot be found in this way.  Please stop calling an "unintentional object retention" a "memory leak".  If "unintentional object retention" is too awkward, then try "memory hoarding".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a list of open source tools you can look at: http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers . Of course, JMap and JConsole are also possible solutions.

Answer (score 4):

A tool like [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) will help to find greedy memory pigs and has even a memory leak detector.

The memory profiler of [Visual VM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) might also help if you need to go at a lower level.

Answer (score 3):

The last time I looked into free profilers, they weren't nearly as good as the established commercial ones.

I recommend evaluating

- [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)

  [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/)

  [JProbe](http://www.quest.com/jprobe/)

and investing the money for a license of the tool you like best.

A good profiler, compared to a bad one, can easily save you a day of debugging work immediately and that pays for the license (and for the people doing the great job developing these nice tools).

All three plug into Eclipse and allow you to start profiling directly from Eclipse, from your current project, so there is no tedious work to set up the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 1):

[Sun's VisualVM](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) is free, but I am a big fan of [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/) which is a commercial app, although you can get a 30 day trial.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with tools that come with JDK, jconsole and jmap. There is [good article about JVM monitoring](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/monitoring/) on java.sun.com.