# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, How to find and fix?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I'm trying to programming a crossword creator. using a given dictionary txt file and a given pattern txt file. The basic idea is using DFS algorithm. the problem begin when the dictionary file is v-e-r-y big (about 50000 words). then i recive the :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

i know that there is a part in my program that wastes memory, but i don't know where it is, how to find it and how to fix it

Comment: "How to find" is covered by this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840421/whats-a-good-free-tool-for-investigating-unintentional-object-retention-in-java

Answer (score 3):

Does it really waste memory ? If you're loading a sizeable dictionary, then you may simply want to increase the JVM memory settings (the JVM has a maximum memory allocation - dependent on your platform, and configurable).

e.g.

```
$ java -Xmx512m ....
```

would increase the maximum memory allocation of the JVM to 512m.

If you think you have a memory leak (garbage collection not kicking in due to references not being released) then a profiler such as [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) may be of use. Note that this isn't free, but the trial version may help you solve your problem.

Comment: hey, i already tried to increase the JVM memory..
Do you have maybe another advise?

Comment: Have you tried profiling it ?

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, what is profiling?

Comment: Running the program with some sort of tool (e.g. YourKit) and getting statistics/metrics out such that you can determine where the bottlenecks (e.g. memory consumption) are.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem ( in linux based os ) do following

1) **increase memory** (so that this problem don't come frequently ) by configuring "domain.xml" in

/glassfish/domain/domain1/config

search for

`<jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=`

`set it to higher value eg- 198m or 256m`

2) kill the glassfish process to free the port on which it was running ( **in my case it was 8686**)
 open terminal (in linux based os) and type -

`sudo netstat -npl | grep 8686`

this will result in something like..

`tcp6 0 0 :::8686 :::* LISTEN 3452/java`

next use

`kill -9 3452` to kill that process ( 3452 in this case )

Now try to start glassfish, it should start.

Answer (score 0):

Some Times, I have seen people initialize variables in loop like

```
While(condition){

    String s="tttt";

}
```

This should be avoided as it waste lot of memory.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily waste memory (and your example definitely doesn't, as string literals are pooled). It can even help as garbage collection of young objects is cheaper than collecting old objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot..this is something i wasn't not knowing.It really makes my day.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem. I've run into it once or twice, and increasing heap size doesn't help. Solving it with VM settings - you may even want to decrease the heap size (it once worked for me). You may also want to test different garbage collectors, I've had success using the [G1 collector](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/g1_intro.jsp).

General advice on how to avoid this error is also hard (or so it seemed to me when I researched this matter to solve my own problems). [High infant mortality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Generational_GC_.28aka_Ephemeral_GC.29) is probably good, since young objects are cheaper to collect than old ones.

Answer (score 0):

large dictionary...mmm.. is there an absolute requirement of storing that directly in the memory of the jvm?

A lazy chap like myself would store this in a database (in-memory even perhaps? - hypersonic for example), transfer the responsibility of searching through a list to the  database while my program worked on creating interesting symmetric black and white square combinations :)

Just a thought though.